# Document.on("Submit") is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple form, where we need to enter the details and on submission, it hits the controller and return the confirmation message.

My issue is, the submit button never hits Jquery .on submit function. Following is my code.

```
 <form id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax-form class='contact_us'>
                                            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="text" name="fphone" id="fphone" placeholder="_____-______" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="email" name="femail" id="femail" placeholder="your@email.com" class="form-control">
                                            <input class="online_deal_form form-control" id="send1" type="submit" value="View Online Quote">
                                        </form>
```

Following is my jquery code:

```
 $(document).on("submit","[data-ajax-form]",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loaderSVG').show();
            var $form = $(this);
            var data = $form.serialize();
// does an ajax call to controller
...
});
```

Instead of hitting jquery function, it is doing a post-back directly to controller, which gives me a IIS 404 error.

I have multiple forms present on a page with different class names, for that reason I'm using `data-ajax-form` and handle the submit events.

I don't exactly know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated !!

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use `$("[data-ajax-form]").submit()`?

Comment: @Luca same as Luca except $("[data-ajax-form]").on('submit', function(e) {}); ?? Does it make a difference if you make this change?

Comment: @Luca: given the attribute is `data-ajax-form` I'm going to guess the form is loaded using AJAX, so isn't in the DOM on page load.  As such, `$("[data-ajax-form]")` won't select it. `$(document).on("submit","[data-ajax-form]");` will.

Comment: @Mike that has nothing to do with whether the form was loaded through AJAX or was hard-coded into the page. I don't understand your assumption.

Comment: @daddygames Event Delegation.... what is hard to understand about it?

Comment: @epascarello Mike assumes the form was added by AJAX because of the property existing. The existence of a property does not automatically assume that the element was loaded using AJAX. If this is a RAZOR-specific thing then that may be why it was assumed. I am unfamiliar with RAZOR

Comment: So OP, are there any errors occurring when you submit? (Make sure to check the box to preserver the log)

Comment: @epascarello No, It doesn't give me any errors. It just does and postback call directly to controller and gives me a 404 page error

Comment: So are you positive the JavaScript above is actually running? aka, the line is actually binding the event.

Comment: javascript is working fine but my question is why it doesnot hit the break point when I keep a break in this function, instead it gives me a 404 IIS page.

Comment: Why 404? because the form is posting and you are not cancelling it so the JavaScript code you have attached is not running.

Comment: @epascarello yes, exactly. Why is my javascript is not getting attached to form ?

Comment: It prevents default on submit as expected in snippet so I still dont understand

Comment: @ISHIDA it is impossible for us to debug, your code works so there is something that we can not see that is causing the issue.

Comment: @epascarello working on it.

Comment: @epascarello https://expirebox.com/download/403ab3e088d4aeac716572f8105f385a.html can you please download the file from here. It is the html file which I'm getting an error.

Comment: @Mike I suspect `data-ajax-form` means it should be submitted using AJAX rather than that it was loaded via AJAX. But delegation works with static elements, too (it's just not necessary), so this should work.

Comment: @epascarello Did you get the file ??

Comment: @epascarello Did you get chance to look at the file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out alternative way to fix this.

```
$(document).on("submit","[data-ajax-form]",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loaderSVG').show();
            var $form = $(this);
            var data = $form.serialize();
// does an ajax call to controller
...
});
```

Changed to

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loaderSVG').show();
            var $form = $(this);
            var data = $form.serialize();
// does an ajax call to controller
...
});
```

This fixed my issue. 
Thank you everyone for suggestions